# Android native build error. clang++: error: unknown argument: '-fconcepts-ts'

Tags: c++, android-ndk, build.gradle

I am using code where auto is used for function. It compiles well on gcc compiler on linux machine. When I using the same function in android native, it is throwing the error

clang++: error: unknown argument: '-fconcepts-ts'

-fconcepts-ts is optional on linux machine as without it , we only get a warning.
But for android native build, I am not understanding where to fix this.

I updated build.gradle to reflect the cppflags for c++17
cppFlags '-std=c++17'
However, it is not recognizing the -fconcepts-ts flag at all.

Please help.

Comment: "`-fconcepts-ts` is optional on linux machine" - Since the program does not use C++20 concepts, removing `-fconcepts-ts` from the compilation command for Android should also work.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error now with android build. The CXX_STANDARD property on target "x" contained an invalid value: "20".    Note that this did not come when value was 17.

Comment: The version of Clang that comes with the version of NDK that's being used likely does not support C++20, but your CMake project (or a dependency of it) requires C++20. You may try to use newer NDK, or to lower the required C++ standard version. If you have a new question, open a new question to avoid extended discussion in the comments.